# Where to get wireless driver for Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-10.04, broadcom

Does anybody know where I can get broadcom wlan 1397 half minicard 4312bg drivers for ubuntu?

Comment: Have you made sure that you ticked the box saying that you are prepared to use proprietary drivers?

Comment: Yes, that was my problem.  You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you made sure that you ticked the box saying that you are prepared to use proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good start for any Linux not just for Ubuntu if you need Broadcom stuff not included in your distribution: [LinuxWireless.org](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43)

Comment: I've had some issues with an older wireless driver that worked in U-9.10 and fails in U-10.4.  Looks like this link could help me too, so thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Never had a Broadcom wireless myself, but I thought the Broadcom proprietary drivers worked.

http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

Comment: I worked with about 5-6 different broadcom chipsets for wireless and other 5-6 for bluetooth. Some chipsets/models are working out-of-the-box, other don't. The broadcom proprietary drivers are also sometimes not working. However, the linuxwireless project is almost all the time can give you a solution.